# How to call this function in my twig

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

**Table1(ediTransaction)->filename

Table2(edi997Details)->trans**

I'm creating a page where I'm going to display the filename and its trans. My aim is I want to display the filename's corresponding trans with the same transactionId. I got stuck with this, I can't display its trans but got an error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 86 near 'b WHERE a.ediTransaction':
>   Error: Class Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Entity\Edi997Details has no
>   association named edi997Details") in
>   MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:asn.html.twig at line 88.

**TWIG**

```
  {% for trans in trans %}
        <td>
           {{trans.ediTransaction.fileName}}
        </td>
       <td>
       {%
         set trans=render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getStatus',{'ediTransactionId' : trans.ediTransactionId}))
       %} //this is for calling the trans and I think this is wrong. Help me with this one.
      </td>
     {% endfor %}
```

**CONTROLLER** //for the filename and this works fine

```
 public function FileAction(Request $request,$page) {

    $fileName      = $request->query->get('fileName');
    $sort          = $request->query->get('sort');

    $max_records = 15 ;
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $data = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction')->getAsnDetails($fileName, $page, 15);

    $count = $data->count();
    $pagination = array(
      'page'          => $page,
      'route'         => 'matrix_edi_asn',
      'route_params'  => array(),
      'fileName'      => $fileName,
      'sort'          => $sort
    );

    if ($max_records > 0 ) {
      $pagination['pages_count'] = max(ceil($count / $max_records), 1);
      return $this->render('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:asn.html.twig', array('trans' => $data,'pagination' => $pagination));
    }
  }
```

**CONTROLLER FOR TRANS (needs more edit, a function for calling trans)**

```
 public function getStatusAction($ediTransactionId) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $trans = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:Edi997Details')->getStatus($ediTransactionId);
    $response = 0;

    if($trans != null) {
      foreach ($trans as $key) {
        $noOfTrans = $key->getnoOfTrans();

        $response = $noOfTrans;
      }
    }
    return new Response($response);
  }
```

**Edi997DetailsRepository (where the trans is located )**

```
public function getStatus($ediTransactionId){
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT a,b FROM MatrixEdiBundle:edi997Details a
                 JOIN a.ediTransaction b
                 WHERE a.ediTransaction = :TransactionId')
                 ->setParameter('TransactionId', $ediTransactionId);

                return $query->getResult();

        }
```

I've encountered a lot of error with this and I know theres something wrong with my code and I need someone who can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: `for trans in trans` - and then later in the iteration `set trans=`. You're overriding the same variable over and over. That's a sure way to disaster in loops. Use different variable names.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a backslash instead of a colon (`:`) here `SELECT a,b FROM MatrixEdiBundle:edi997Details a`? (I'm assuming that `MatrixEdiBundle:edi997Details` suppose to be the model?)